# Spring Boot logback is creating tmp file but not deleting them

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, rollingfileappender

I'm having problem with my Logback in Java/Spring Boot application.

My Logback is keep creating large tmp files and it's taking over lots of disk usage.

This is how my **RollingFileAppender** in logback-config.xml looks like

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
   <file>${appName}.log</file>

   <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${appName}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
      <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
   </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

I'm aware that **TimeBasedRollingPolicy** rolls file every 00:00 in my option.

I've seend that **%i** option is needed for rolling index, and I tried it but **%i** option is not available in **TimeBasedRollingPolicy** and it's only used is **SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy**.

Why is my logback keep creating large tmp files?

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Thank you.

ps. I know I can solve this issue by using **SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy** and **%i** option, but I'm curious why this options is keep creating big tmp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let see why the problem is :**

- You did not specify any `timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy` inside `rollingPolicy`

**How we can fix it :**

- We can set a triggering police for every 5 mb size file can be archive to another folder
- consider below sample `rollingPolicy` to avoid large log file

```
<property name="LOGS" value="${logging.file.path}" />
```

- sample `rollingPolicy`

```
<appender name="RollingFile"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/info/app_info.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 5 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/info/archived/app_info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
```

Comment: Hi. I faced another problem. My logging files started to roll when it reaches the "maxFileSize" option. But one of my .gz file cannot be seend with "unexpected end of file" error and keeps leaving .tmp file.

Comment: could you pls try reload your pom dependency and try a clean run